# SaveWICTextureToFile and SwapChainPanel with DirectXTK

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, directx-11

I'm trying to use the SaveWICTextureToFile method from DirectXTK to grab a screenshot in my Windows Store app (Windows 8.1). I'm using XAML with a SwapChainPanel element. Unfortunately, the method always saves a rectangle of the screen size filled with solid color rather than the current screen content. Every time I call the SaveWICTextureToFile method it saves a different color.

This is my code (simplified):

```
void DirectXPage::SaveButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    critical_section::scoped_lock lock(m_main->GetCriticalSection());

    auto folder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder;

    WCHAR fname[_MAX_PATH];
    wcscpy_s(fname, folder->Path->Data());
    wcscat_s(fname, L"\\screenshot.png");

    auto context = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDeviceContext();
    auto swapChain = m_deviceResources->GetSwapChain();

    ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(*backBuffer), (LPVOID*)&backBuffer);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        HRESULT hr = SaveWICTextureToFile(context, backBuffer, GUID_ContainerFormatPng, fname);

        DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);

        // ... mode code for FileSavePicker etc.
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Leszek